# Relating Thermodynamic & Transport Properties to Electrochemical discharge curve

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

What are the fundamental thermodynamic & transport properties that the discharge cycle of a rechargeable battery with an intercalating cathode (like Li-ion) should depend upon? The few that I could think of are

1. transport properties of the ion through electrolye & cathode material.
2. stress/strain properties of the cathode material due to intercalation.
3. chemical interaction of the solvent & ions with the cathode material.
4. electrochemical potential difference between anode & cathode.

My question is what formalism relates all these properties systematically to the experimentally observed discharge curve such as voltage as a function of capacity, repeatability of discharge curves etc.